# How to generate a X509 certifcate for testing with Certbot

Tags: https, openssh, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

I don't understand how to use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). I tried:

```
sudo certbot certonly --email hello@world.com --webroot -w . -d chris.ca
```

and it tells me:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: chris.ca
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://chris.ca/.well-known/acme-challenge/Hp97XAo-GFK2jnv9WU9qJ12Hg5cI4ldxDkBbXLt-Vf4:
   "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <h"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

For testing I want to create a certificate for my own use. So how do I achieve that? How do I create a certificate that the browser will accept?

Maybe I'm not understanding how the SSL protocol is implemented. But when I generated my own certificates and served my web page with https through nginx, the browser struck out the `https` in the address bar. Furthermore my program was receiving normal http requests rather than https.

So how do I either use certbot to generate a certificate that the browser will accept or how do I setup a testing environment for https in some other way?

Comment: Did you check the list of [available tutorials](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions/)? It doesn't look like chris.ca is serving any content right now? There are multiple redirects? If you want a self signed certificate there are numerous tutorials but beware that a self signed certificate will never be accepted by default. Your website essentially serves the wrong content. The link `http://chris.ca/.well-known/acme-challenge/Hp97XAo-GFK2jnv9WU9qJ12Hg5cI4ldxDkBbXLt-Vf4`redirects to `bonte.ca` instead of serving the message it should which is needed for authentication.

Comment: `accepted by default`, can I configure the browser to accept my cert? Let's say so that the https is not struck out anymore?

Comment: With a self signed one you'd have to run your own CA and import the CA cert into your browser store of trusted CAs. After that certs (e.g. for your server) issued by that CA wouldn't be "red" anymore. This would only apply to people that import your CAs root cert into their store.

Comment: I tried importing it to the trusted root certificates (something like that) without success. So I guess the question is how do you successfully generate a CA from the two .pem files that nginx reads?

Comment: That depends on what you did. You'd use your CA key to sign a CSR and generate a CRT for your server. After that you'd import your CA CRT into your Certificate Store and and tell nginx to use the signed CRT and his private key file. This is without an Intermediate CA which would mean you'd need to build a bundle and sign some more. But still: This is only working for computers under your control where you imported the root CRT. Fixing your webserver configuration to allow serving the acme-challenge would get your a certificate which is accepted by most browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You chose the webroot method to authenticate that you're the the owner of the domain. As such a file is placed under `.well-known/acme-challenge/` that needs to serve a certain content (the filename usually). But your website (as it is redirecting any requests to `bonte.ca`) doesn't deliver that content but instead some HTML (you can see the start of that in the error).

Comment: yes but if I remove the --webroot option I still get `make sure that your domain name was entered correctly`

Comment: Yes because your webserver configuration is wacky. If you're not using the webroute method you'd need to use the DNS to authenticate your ownership. It doesn't look like that's supported by CertBot. As such you'd have to change your webserver configuration to actually serve the content in `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`.